# Code to clip out whitespace in margin with R

Tags: r

My mentor and I are fairly new to using R and we need some help. We are exporting a rasterized image as a tiff but cannot get rid of a white margin that only appears on the exported file. Any help would be appreciated, thanks in advance.

```
tiff(file = "MyImage.tiff", width=1028,height=1028, res=150)
  plot(Image, breaks=breakpoints,col=colors, axes=FALSE, legend=FALSE)
  dev.off()
```

Comment: please include a reproducible example

Comment: Does that help? We are also working on getting a picture on too.

Comment: Tony. please see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example. The aim is tol allow people to run your code and see the same issue as you